# Error in Migration to Webpack 4. Receiving Error: Chunk.parents

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm migrating from "webpack": "^3.8.1" to "webpack": "^4.41.2"

Receiving this Error. I moved already from CommonsChunkPlugin to SplitChunksPlugin.

```
ERROR in   Error: Chunk.parents: Use ChunkGroup.getParents() instead

  - Chunk.js:844 Chunk.get
    [order-platform]/[webpack]/lib/Chunk.js:844:9

  - index.js:40 doesChunkBelongToHTML
    [order-platform]/[preload-webpack-plugin]/index.js:40:30

  - index.js:116 extractedChunks.filter.chunk
    [order-platform]/[preload-webpack-plugin]/index.js:116:61

  - Array.filter

  - index.js:116 compilation.plugin
    [order-platform]/[preload-webpack-plugin]/index.js:116:45


  - new Promise


  - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesWaterfallHook.lazyCompileHook
    [order-platform]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

  - index.js:673 
    [order-platform]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:673:47

  - index.js:178 Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then.then.html
    [order-platform]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:178:18
```